# When selecting channel entries, only select entries in just the top-level category

Tags: channel-entries, conditionals, categories

I have a channel with entries in categories and subcategories. I want to output a list of only the entries that are not in the subcategories. Is there a way to do an "only A" or "A & not anything else" type of selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look to use [GWCode Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation). You have the same control over inclusions and exclusions but a whole load more on top. `excl_cat_id` and `excl_cat_id_children` could be useful here if the categories are relatively fixed and you know their IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Dandy Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dandy-cat). it allow really crazy stuff on categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
category=""
```

parameter.

You can exclude all child categories

```
category="not 2|14|16"
```

or specify all parent categories

```
category="1|3|4"
```

Check out the docs: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#category

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if this works, though. Edit: sorry, hit enter. I tried dynamically building a list (a|b|c) of every category but the one to show, but in the docs it says "If you are using exclusion (category="not 3|4") and an entry is in a category that is not excluded, the entry will be returned even if it also belongs to an excluded category." Is there a way around that?

Comment: It means that when an entry has a parent AND a child category it will be displayed, even though the child category is excluded. Just make sure you turn off auto-assign parent categories (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#auto-assign-category-parents) and you should be fine.

Comment: Turning off auto-assign seems to meet my needs nicely (assuming nobody else comes back and changes the categories.)